# C++ vector accumulates

Tags: c++, vector, accumulate

I was trying to use the accumulate function for vectors

```
vector <double> A;
double B = 0;

A.reserve(100);
for(itr = 0; itr < 210; itr++)
{
    term1 = pow(r[itr], 12);
    term1 = 1/term1;
    term2 = pow(r[itr], 6);
    term2 = 2/term2;
    A.push_back(term1 - term2);
}
B = accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
```

however, I always got B = 0, while A had nonzero values

Comment: Could we see the code that fills A?

Comment: You should post a minimal code example reproducing your problem. This piece of code doesn't really help.

Comment: More code required exception.

Comment: This piece of code really does not help. Right now we can only say: you wrote a bug in `[...]`

Comment: still doesn't change anything, I still get 0

Comment: @parapura: how `resize` is supposed to help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`std::accumulate` is a bit sneaky in the sense that the type of the result is the type of the initial value, and *not* the type of the container elements! So your accumulator produces `int`s.

To fix this, accumulate into a `double`:

```
accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0.0);
//                             ^^^^^^^ literal of type double
```

Answer (score 2):

the key may be how your are doing [...] //Fill values into A
`
    vector  A
    double B = 0;

```
A.reserve(100);
A.push_back(1);
A.push_back(2);
B = accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
return 0;
```

resolves B = 3.0

if after the reserve you are doing a[0] = 1
this is bad code.
what you might want to do instead is say resize.

reserve only gives you the backing memory capacity, it doesn't actually create the valid iterators.. so A.begin() still equals A.end()

looking at code change, do you know the difference between integer and double math?
are term1 and term 2 integral?

Comment: they are doubles, and I was having a problem with the accumulate statement (I had to put in 0.0)...pretty sneaky