# Use class method as `op` argument to `accumulate`

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to create a class that calculates its variance from a `vector<float>`. It should do this by using its previously calculated `this->mean` in `diffSquaredSum`. I'm trying to call the method `diffSquaredSum` inside of `accumulate` but have no idea what the magical syntax is.

What is the correct syntax to use the `diffSquaredSum` class method as the `op` argument to `accumulate` in `setVariance`?

```
float diffSquaredSum(float sum, float f) {
    // requires call to setMean
    float diff = f - this->mean;
    float diff_square = pow(diff,2);
    return sum + diff_square;
}

void setVariance(vector<float>& values) {
    size_t n = values.size();
    double sum = accumulate(
        values.begin(), values.end(), 0, 
        bind(this::diffSquaredSum));
    this->variance = sum / n;
}
```

Comment: why you need `bind` at all?

Comment: When I call it with just `diffSquaredSum` I get `no matching function for call to ‘accumulate(std::vector<float>::iterator, std::vector<float>::iterator, int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)`

Comment: try change `0` to `0.f`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ vector accumulates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227610/c-vector-accumulates)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because it uses the op argument of accumulate. It is not a duplicate of others that do use op because it is using a class method as op. The proposed duplicate doesn't even use op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double sum = std::accumulate(
  values.begin(),
  values.end(),
  0.f,
  [&](float sum, float x){ return diffSquaredSum(sum,x);}
);
```

`bind` is only rarely useful.  Prefer lambdas, they are easier to write and read.

You could instead get fancy with binding, but why?

Comment: @bryanchen those are methods in the OP -- they use `this`.  You end up having to bind `this`, and who has the time for that syntax?

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for bringing some much needed competence to this question thread.